# Applying Shadowbox.js on dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I m using shadowbox.js for image gallery display.

for this we have to generate html like this

```
<a href="images/Ganesha3602.jpg" rel="shadowbox[my]"><img src="images/thumb.jpg"   alt="First" title="First image" /></a>
<a href="images/original.jpg" rel="shadow[my]"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="Second" title="Second image" /></a>
<a href="images/original.jpg" rel="shadowbox[my]"><img src="images/thumb.jpg" alt="First" title="First image" /></a>
```

and then apply `Shadowbox.init()` on body load. Its working like a charm when the above html is static. But when i generate it dynamically using `$.ajax` and call `Shadowbox.init()` on success; shadowbox does not work. I also tried calling  `Shadowbox.init()` on complete.

My code is something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','#load_posts_comments',function(){

    $.ajax({
        url:"post_comment_json.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:{user_id:"123"},
        success: function(data){
            load_posts_comments(data);
        },
        complete: function(){
            Shadowbox.init();
        }
    });
});
```

Where am I going wrong? I looked the shadowbox website but there was no documentation regarding dynamically loaded content. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: yeah I had tried that too but it did not work

Comment: Could this answer help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144577/shadowbox-stops-working-after-jquery-function-call

Comment: @Niklas thanks man .. You saved my day. :)

using this code worked


Shadowbox.clearCache();
Shadowbox.setup();

Comment: I've posted an answer in case they don't close this as a duplicate =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reinitialize it by using `Shadowbox.clearCache();` and `Shadowbox.setup();`.
It's been explained much better here: [shadowbox stops working after jquery function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144577/shadowbox-stops-working-after-jquery-function-call)