# Lightbox not firing from dynamic page created with an xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, xmlhttprequest, lightbox

I have a page containing an empty div that is populated with a particular page's content depending on what link the user clicks.

I'm using jquery's xmlhttprequest and the GET to grab these particular php files which was working just fine. The div in question is also animated to slide up into view with the various content which is where I ran into my first problem. I wanted a close button that would slide the page back out of sight and couldn't get it to work until I used the following:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.closer', function(event){
    $('.panel').stop().animate({"top" : 9999},5500);
    });
```

My frustration is now that I have the page populating, animating and closing all well-and-fine, I went to implement a lightbox (in this case shadowbox.js) and I can't seem to get the dynamic page and the lightbox function to connect. I've tried using the above method and switching some things around, but to no avail.

I've scoured stackoverflow for a solution, and while I'm sure it's on here somewhere, I think my lack of vocabulary in using the right terminology has left me with no other option than to post.

Thanks in advance for any help one may have.
Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that a problem is that shadowbox doesn't see the dynamic loaded content, so you need to reinitialize shadowbox. Look at this answer:
[Applying Shadowbox.js on dynamically generated content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408993/applying-shadowbox-js-on-dynamically-generated-content)